# java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject when sending string response from the server

Tags: php, android, codeigniter

I am sending data to server from android application through genAsync library. On server I am inserting and checking if user is already exist simultaneously.if user is already exist than I am sending json_encoded array and if user not exist than im sending **message** that is user inserted successfully but when im sending message to application it gives an error that is  **java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject**

Im attaching the php codes,android codes and error log also.

**php codes**

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{

  public function create(){

    $data=$this->check_exist($this->input->post('user_id'));
    if($data=='0')
    {

        $this->load->model('UsersModel');
        $msg = $this->UsersModel->create();
        if ($msg==true) {
            echo 'user inserted successfully';
        } else {
            echo '0';
        }
    }
    else{
        $data["user_details"]=$data;
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
  }
  public function check_exist($user_id)
    {
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->load->model('UsersModel');
      $data=$this->UsersModel->user_exist($user_id);
      if(!empty($data))
      {
        return($data);
      }
      else
      {
        return '0';
      }
   }
}
```

**android codes for sending data to server side**

```
try {
           final Database_Helper dg = new Database_Helper(getBaseContext());
           ServerUrl obj =new ServerUrl();
           HashMap postData = new HashMap();
           postData.put("user_id",personId);
           postData.put("user_name",personName);
           postData.put("email",personEmail);              
           postData.put("profile_picture",String.valueOf(personPhoto));
           final PostResponseAsyncTask readTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(UserLogin.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() 
              {

                public void processFinish(String mStringArray) 
                  {
                     Log.w("data", mStringArray.toString());
                     try {
                           JSONObject json= null;
                           json = new JSONObject(mStringArray);
                           JSONArray jsonscoresarray=json.getJSONArray("user_details");
                           final JSONObject details = jsonscoresarray.getJSONObject(0);
                          if (jsonscoresarray.length() == 0) 
                          {
                            //storing data to sqlite if user not exist
                            dg.user_Putrecord(dg, personId, personName, personEmail, String.valueOf(personPhoto));
                          }
                          else
                          {
                             //storing data to sqlite if user exist
          dg.user_Putrecord(dg,details.getString("auth_id"),details.getString("full_name"),details.getString("email_id"),details.getString("profile_url"));
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, mStringArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            });
                            obj.url("Users","create");
                            readTask.execute(obj.domain_url);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                         Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

**Here is my error logcat**

```
01-29 13:49:33.765 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 1 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-29 13:49:33.765 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-29 13:49:33.765 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
01-29 13:49:33.765 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
01-29 13:49:33.765 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at com.example.ali.ansofexperts.UserLogin$4$1.processFinish(UserLogin.java:121)
01-29 13:49:33.765 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at com.kosalgeek.asynctask.PostResponseAsyncTask.onPostExecute(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:248)
01-29 13:49:33.765 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at com.kosalgeek.asynctask.PostResponseAsyncTask.onPostExecute(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:31)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
01-29 13:49:33.766 4455-4455/com.example.ali.ansofexperts W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

i just want to know how can i handle this exception when string  response is sended from server.

Comment: on which line do you get this error?

Comment: Share your POJO class please.

Comment: @VladMatvienko  JSONArray jsonscoresarray=json.getJSONArray("user_details"); when string response is sended by server

Comment: It is likely wrong. There is nothing about `JSONObject` on that line. Make sure that it is not the line above, or a line below.

Comment: @VladMatvienko but my error logcat is showing error on that line

Answer (score 1):

I am posting full answer for beginners.

**there is little bit changes in your php codes as I am writing it below**

```
public function create(){
    $this->load->model('UsersModel');
    $data=$this->UsersModel->check_exist($this->input->post('user_id'));
    if($data==0){
        $nData=$this->UsersModel->create();
        if($nData!="0"){
        $data=$this->UsersModel->check_exist($this->input->post('user_id'));
            echo json_encode($data);        
        }else{
            die("0");
        }

    }else{
            $result["user_details"]=$data;
            echo json_encode($result);
    }

}
```

as you can see i just removed your check_exist function from Controller. Because
there no need of this function in your controller.

So I am directly calling it from model so as to reduce the number of line of codes.

**Now android side coding changes**

```
   try {
          final Database_Helper dg = new Database_Helper(getBaseContext());
             ServerUrl obj =new ServerUrl();
             HashMap postData = new HashMap();
             postData.put("user_id",personId);
             postData.put("user_name",personName);
             postData.put("email",personEmail);

             postData.put("profile_picture",String.valueOf(personPhoto));
             final PostResponseAsyncTask readTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(UserLogin.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() 
              {               
               public void processFinish(String mStringArray) 
               {
                 Log.d("data", mStringArray);
                 if(mStringArray.equals("0"))
                 {
                  Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Invalid login try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }
                 else 
                 {
                 try {
                      JSONObject json = null;
                      json = new JSONObject(mStringArray);
                      JSONArray jsonscoresarray = json.getJSONArray("user_details");
                       final JSONObject details = jsonscoresarray.getJSONObject(0);
                       if (mStringArray.equals("0")) 
                       {                      
                         Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "At if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       } 
                       else 
                       {                      
                        Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "At else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
                      Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } 
                 catch (JSONException e)
                 {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }

           }

        });
       obj.url("Users","create");
       readTask.execute(obj.domain_url);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If a user does not exists your method returns the integer `0`. Then you are trying to add an array index to it.

Try to seperate your result and data array like that:

```
$exists = $this->check_exist($this->input->post('user_id'));

$result = [];

if(!$exists) {
    // code from above
} else {
    $result["user_details"]=$data;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Applying an array index to an integer should raise an Warning anyway:

https://3v4l.org/9qU7r

Answer (score 0):

You might not be getting data with `key = "user_details"`

Have a key check before using it, like:

```
if(json.has("user_details")) {
    JSONArray jsonscoresarray=json.getJSONArray("user_details");

    ... other code here ...

} else {
    Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Edit:**

The issue is at line

```
json = new JSONObject(mStringArray);
```

, maybe you are getting response as `0` and since it is not any jsonObject, you get Exception of cannot convert Integer to JsonObject

Use below code to check if it is valid json and then process accordingly:

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String myString) {
    try {
        new JSONObject(myString);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        // e.g. in case JSONArray is valid as well...
        try {
            new JSONArray(myString);
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

now in your code use:

```
if(isValidJson(mStringArray)) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mStringArray);
    JSONArray jsonscoresarray=json.getJSONArray("user_details");

    ... other code here ...

} else {
    // Response Not Json
    Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: what value you receive in: `Log.w("data", mStringArray.toString());`

Comment: When user exist it return Json array and when user not exist then it return 1

Comment: You need to have a check if the response is `Json` or not. Check my updated answer.